# MVC3 C# Linq (Where / if)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to insert if statement within Where in a model,

```
q = from vw_masterview in ctx.vw_MasterViews
where 
vw_masterview.LastDate <= toDate &&
vw_masterview.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId
```

AllowedOfficeId could be null, I would like to add if statment

```
q = from vw_masterview in ctx.vw_MasterViews
    where 
    vw_masterview.LastDate <= toDate &&
    ***if (MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId != null)***
    vw_masterview.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your query using the fluent notation and apply an additional `Where` statement when `AllowedOfficeId` isn't null:

```
var query = ctx.vw_MasterViews.Where(v => v.LastDate <= toDate);
if (MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId != null)
{
    query = query.Where(v => v.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId);
}
```

Then you can either run the query or continue to build it up, such as using the `Select` method to retrieve specific properties or project into an anonymous type or new class.

Answer (score 2):

```
q = from vw_masterview in ctx.vw_MasterViews
    where
        vw_masterview.LastDate <= toDate &&
        (
            (MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId != null) &&
            (vw_masterview.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId)
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it worked well.  I just found that I am using it again in the following: (Decimal)ctx.vw_MasterViews.Where(c => c.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId).Count().  I would appreciate your assistance

Comment: `(Decimal) ctx.vw_MasterViews.Count(c => (MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId != null) && (c.OfficeId == MemberRepository.AllowedOfficeId))`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did not get any errors, however I get null value becasue I think the query still applying null value to AllowedOfficeId.  What I am trying to do is to omitt AllowedOfficeId from where statement if it is null.